# how to create a drawable for a splash screen background from 2 colors?

Tags: android, splash-screen, drawable, android-drawable, xml-drawable

I'm trying to create a background for a splash screen from 2 different colors one on top of the other, each exactly half of the screen, like so:

[image: 2 colors full screen background]

I have tried the following but it does not work for every device because of the specified size.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#abc123" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="436dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#456def" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Does anyone know of a way to create that full screen drawable background?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use weight/percentage dimensions in this file, you have to implement this in your layout file